# infer function args type by hint typescript

Tags: typescript

I usually have code like this, but TS cant infer types of func args because it doesn't know context.

Is there any way to hint compiler type of function?

```
router.get('/get', imget);
router.get('/send', imsend);

function imget(req, res, next) { }
function imsend(req, res, next) { }

export = router;
```

I tried different kinds of type assertion but all of them result in syntax error.

Something like:

```
function imget(req, res, next) { } as express.RequestHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables / const e.g.

```
const imget: express.RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => { }
```

## More

- Some inference docs : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-inference.html

Comment: But it prevents function hoisting! :(